# script line with pointers when you click on it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out what is the right term for it so I can research more into and learn.
I encountered this tab, where you click on one the heading the blue line and a pointer pop up to point towards the tab content... (for example when you click on Books, and then click on Articles, etc etc..
Here is the example..

http://www.sutherlandlibrary.com/tabs/library-tabs-v4.htm

I want to know how you can create that. Or what is it ? so I can start researching into it.

Thanks in advanced, I know I'm suppose to search for it first, But i dont know where to start.

Cheers

Comment: `I want to know how you can create that.` A good starting place would be examining that website's source code...

Comment: It's literally called tabs... What's the issue here?

Comment: @Jeremy I'm guessing the OP wants to know how to style the downwards arrow selection indicator using CSS?

Comment: @Asad Ah, okay. Thanks for clarifying. OP: check out css-tricks.com

Answer (score 1):

Look for CSS3 shapes, for the actual pointy-thing.

There are plugins in ever major framework for creating tabs, or you can create a custom one with some jQuery.  You'll need `.on('click, ...)` and `.fadeIn`/`.fadeOut`

For the tab-view use the CSS `position: absolute` on each tab-content inside a container with `position: relative`.

<sub>(community wiki because I didn't actually do any work)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/trevordixon/hvBpF/

Each tab is a `<li>`, and the currently selected tab has a class `current`. You'll see they have the following CSS rule:

```
.tab-features .tabs-list .current {
    background: url("images/feature-tab-arrow.gif") no-repeat center 27px;
}
```

So the tab that has the `current` class has a 27px tall arrow image positioned just below the bottom of the tab. They could have also done something like this instead of using a background image:

```
.tab-features .tabs-list .current:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    /* These borders make it a triangle */
    border-left: 14px solid transparent;
    border-top: 14px solid #0088aa;
    border-right: 14px solid transparent;
}
```

So to implement something like this, find a good tabs script or plugin, and style the currently selected tab like that.

Comment: Hey all, thanks heaps.. I shall start to play around with it...Cheers a thousand

Answer (score 0):

The one from the page you posted uses a simple image [image]
 for an `<li>`element which has the class `.current` on click (jQuery).
That image is positioned with a `background-position: center bottom;` and overlays the horiz. azure line.